# Return JSON response along with a downloadable file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I return a response in terms of a success message along with the generation of a csv file in Django Rest API.
I am able to return a csv file by using Http Response but unable to render the success message as a response on the browsable API page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - and this is a limitation of the HTTP protocol, not a django or DRF one. You can only return one response for a request, and a response cannot be both a json response and a downloadable file at once (different content-types, different response content etc).